# No load connected - damage to amplifier?

Tags: amplifier

Can turning on an audio amplifier without a connected load damage it? 
Can I apply an input signal and crank it up without the load?(for short or long time) Are Valve amps more tricky in this respect?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is no problem for audio amplifiers as these have a voltage output. When no load is connected, no current will flow. For a voltage output amplifier this is OK.

Almost every audio amplifier should be able to operate without a load for any amount of time.

Comment: There are some Tube amps that can't. However, almost every solid state amp can.

Comment: Oops, was assuming solid state only ;-)

Comment: @Dave, what's the problem for tubes, as a matter of interest?

Comment: @transistor, there's normally an output transformer, and with an o/c secondary it looks like an inductor, so \$\small L\frac{di}{dt}\$ can give large voltages.

Comment: More to the point with tube amps - and a very few solid state amps - their stability is only guaranteed with some minimum load. If they have significant (open loop) output impedance, their gain is higher when unloaded, which affects stability. It's definitely a bigger problem with transformer coupled amps (usually tube), so most solid state amps are guaranteed stable regardless of load.